# iphone segmented control and uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UITableView with a segmented control at the top.  When you tap on the different segments, I want the table  to reload with a new different sized array.  I have tried everything including [self.tableView reloadData].  When you click on a different tab now, it only changes the cells that are out of view and does not add any more. Any ideas??? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you are using as your table-backing object. Typically people use an array which is then referenced by cellForRowAtIndexPath. If you are doing this but not updating the Array, then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your numberOfRowsinSection method, are you returning the count of the correct datasource when the segment selection is switched? When you select a segment, you would need to call 'reloadData' on the tableview, you would need to check the count you are returning from 'numberOfRowsInSection' and you would need to use the correct datasource in cellForRowAtIndexPath to provide your cell contents.